# Is it possible for a nested element's background to stretch to an absolute position inside that's in a fixed width/centered parent? [Image inside]

Tags: html, css

[image]

The header text would live inside the wrapper[white] which is centered. The header has a background[green] that is positioned all the way to the left 0px position, which would need to be fluid when resizing. The header text would be left aligned with how the wrapper text is positioned.

Is this possible?

Comment: Could you provide a [jsFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/) of what you have so far? Which browsers/versions do you need to support? Is it explicitly required to support multiple lines of header text?

Comment: I'm working on an example, I'll have one up soon. Well it should be able to gracefully break in older browsers. Multiple lines would be perfect, but if needs limits, I'm ok with that too.

Answer (score 1):

The negative margin will work very well for this!

http://jsfiddle.net/6Dbq8/1/

Comment: This is great, but say you resized the canvas(browser), with it being hardcoded like that, this wouldn't work. That's my problemo

Comment: It can't continue past the width of the headerText per the image example.

I could have the strip's width be that of the wrapper's X or the child, .headerText X position. Can I do that in CSS or with javascript?

Comment: we'll get a little more tricky here and add a background div on the left to fill in the color, then keep the header text the same width as the body text: http://jsfiddle.net/6Dbq8/12/

Answer (score 0):

Yes, try negative margin, or absolute positioning.